# How other person can access my local javascript application( Through my IP Address) using Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: javascript, apache, tomcat

I developed a javascript application ( Video player) for crome/firefox.
I developed and tested in my chrome and firefox and there are no errors.

Other person wants to acces the player through my IP address..( we are both connected by LAN network).. so i installed apache and wanted to share my application folder which look like .... I am using ubuntu 12.04 ..

Folder structure :

...**player.html**

...**player_css.css**

...**JS ( folder)**

............javascript files

...**input Videofile to play**

I started player.html in apache and cannot see anything loaded (CSS, javascript  ..)

Kindly please help me how the other person can see my video player through my IP address using apache tomcat or other servers ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your app via

> `http://localhost/`

you just have to open the port (normally 80) in your router settings (port-forwarding) to proxy access on your ip on port 80 to your computer.

Comment: I need to use apache for this .. how to load my local web application in apache server .. so that other users can access my webpage ..

Comment: @CS5765 create a vhost for your app http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html